# Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) doesn't send command line to screensavers (.scr files)

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, screensaver

I am currently writing an app to start the screensaver on Windows 10 and show the screen instead of a black background. So that Bubbles and relatives can act like in older OS version.

Here is my full code:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class DrawOverMyScreen {
  public static void Main(string[] CommandLine) {
    switch (CommandLine[0]) {
      case "/c":
        DialogResult Answer = MessageBox.Show("What do you want to do?\n\n - Press \"Yes\" to configure the screensaver\n - Press \"No\" to change the screensaver\n - Press \"Cancel\" to do nothing", "DrawOverMyScreen Configuration", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3);
        switch (Answer) {
          case DialogResult.Yes:
            Screensaver("/c");
            break;

          case DialogResult.No:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            break;

          default:
            break;
        }
        break;

      default:
        Screensaver("/s");
        break;
    }
  }

  public static void Screensaver(string CommandLine) {
    RegistryKey Settings = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\DrawOverMyScreen");
    if (Settings != null) {
      string ScreensaverLocation = Settings.GetValue("Screensaver", string.Empty).ToString();
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ScreensaverLocation) && File.Exists(ScreensaverLocation)) {
        Process Screensaver = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(ScreensaverLocation, CommandLine));
        Screensaver.WaitForExit();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the `Screensaver` method. It uses `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(ScreensaverLocation, CommandLine));` to start the screensaver. But whenever I do `Screensaver("/c");` to run the screensaver's config utility, I only get the normal screensaver view (The one you get when idle after a certain time). Using the run prompt like this: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SCREEN~1.SCR /c` also gives the same result, but command line prompt actually opens the config utility.

Why won't it work, and how can I make it so it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from what you have provided, I can't tell you why it won't work. I do not have a screensaver to test that with (that I know of). But I'm able to do all four of these with Notepad opening a text file:

**Separate ProcessStartInfo**

```
     ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.txt");
     Process proc = Process.Start(procInfo);
     proc.WaitForExit();
```

**Separate ProcessStartInfo with Properties**

```
     ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
     procInfo.Arguments = "c:\\test.txt";
     procInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
     Process proc = Process.Start(procInfo);
     proc.WaitForExit();
```

**Inline ProcessStartInfo**

```
     Process proc = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.txt"));
     proc.WaitForExit();
```

**No PSI, Just Process**

```
     Process proc = Process.Start("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.txt");
     proc.WaitForExit();
```

You may want to go with the first one so that you can breakpoint on the "Process proc..." line and examine the properties of `procInfo`. The `Arguments` property should show the 2nd value (in my case, `c:\\test.txt`), and the `FileName` property should be the path to what you are executing (mine is `notepad.exe`).

*EDIT: I added the separate one with properties so you can really see explicit setting.*

### CONFIGURE A SCREENSAVER

I have worked out an example using the 3D Text screensaver:

```
     string scrPath = @"C:\Windows\System32\ssText3d.scr";
     ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
     procInfo.FileName = scrPath;
     procInfo.Verb = "config";
     procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     Process proc = Process.Start(procInfo);
     proc.WaitForExit();
```

I didn't use the `Arguments`. Instead, I used the `Verb`. This requires `UseShellExecute` to be set to `false`. I got the expected configuration dialog instead of the screensaver running.

**More About Verbs**

This is where the verbs are for screen savers.
[image]

You can also define custom verbs: [Register an Application to Handle Arbitrary File Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx#register_application_arbitrary)

Comment: Your first code block worked with notepad, but not with `ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\ScreenSmelter.scr", "/c");` (brought the screensaver) seems really something related to the file extension `.scr`, since `ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Users\\Charles\\Desktop\\ScreenSmelter.exe", "/c");` worked perfectly fine (it brought the config tool instead of the screensaver). I'll rename the question to specify that it is with a screensaver.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078311/configure-scr-file-from-c-sharp but the answers provided here are dirty hacks, that I'd like to avoid. In the worse case, I'll use it and hide the command prompt that pops up programmatically.

Comment: Yeah, that is ugly. I don't know why Windows hasn't made it work natively with `Process` since it can be executed every other way (command line, etc). At least it's fairly easy to implement.

Comment: I added a section for configuring a screensaver. I don't know if it would work with your particular screensaver, but the way I determined which Verb to use is I put a breakpoint on the line and then examined the "Verbs" collection. In the case of ssText3d.scr, they are `config`, `install`, and `open`. Perhaps this will lead you in a better direction.

Comment: @charles.milette I forgot to mention you in case it doesn't trigger the notification. But, see above.

Comment: It did work with ScreenSmelter, but I will still keep the one with cmd for /p to work, because it isn't in the verbs. Something like two different methods, one for native run, and another for command line run.

Comment: @charles.milette You can add it to the verbs if you need to. I'm not sure if I made the edit in time, but I gave a link on how to extend them. If this is to be used on another computer, then the user will need administrative rights for your installer to add it.

Comment: The /p argument is for the preview in the config tool. It has an window handle also, like `/p 0001`. I need to generate this one dynamically. Since what I am writing is a screensaver for screensavers, I'll simply check for /p in my command line arguments and send it back to the original screensaver.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! A custom verb may still work, but for simplicity's sake, your cmd + /p would probably be easiest.